# how to find number of solutions of $\frac{x^2}{8}=2^{3x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how to find number of solutions of $\frac{x^2}{8}=2^{3x}$

this equation I can write as $x^2=2^{3(x+1)}$

I got one solution for this x=-1

How to find all solutions?

Comment: What values can $x$ take? For example, is $x \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Since $$2^{3x} = (2^3)^x = 8^x,$$ then $$\frac{x^2}{8} = 8^x \Leftrightarrow x^2 = 8^{x + 1} \Leftrightarrow \log_8 x^2 = x + 1 \Leftrightarrow 2\log_8 x = x + 1.$$ Therefore, $x$ is odd. But $8$ is even. Contradiction.

We thus arrive at the conclusion that there exist no integer solutions, i.e. $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user477343: -1 is integer. Contradiction.

Comment: @user355705 Hahah well I guess then $x \notin\mathbb{Z^+}$. This is to say, there exists no solution if $x\geqslant 0$. I should have thought that through a little bit harder :)

Comment: @user355705 What I did not consider was that $8^n\notin\mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow n<0$. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge0$ there is no solution. For $x<0$ , $\dfrac{x^2}{8}$ is strictly decreasing and $8^x$ is strictly increasing so it has the only root you found.

For showing that $\dfrac{x^2}{8}<8^x$ we use the following lemma:

Lemma: for two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ if $f(x_0)>g(x_0)$ for some $x_0$ and $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for $x\ge x_0$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x>0$.

Using this lemma 2 times we conclude what we want:$$\forall x>0\to8^x(\ln 8)^2>\dfrac{1}{4}\to 8^x\ln 8>\dfrac{x}{4}\to 8^x>\dfrac{x^2}{8}$$

Comment: The most subtle point here is to demonstrate that $8^{x+1}>x^2$  for $x>-1$, which is not obvious (though of course true).